# What does "llevarle su vida" mean?

Tags: definiciones, modismos

In a recent conversation with a native speaker from the Dominican Republic, she used the phrase "llevarle su vida". In the context, I took this to mean "live his/her life for him/her" or be controlling over what the other person did. Is this a correct understanding of the phrase?

Comment: Llevarle or llevarse or llevársele? Just to check, as there's a big difference. Who was the subject in the sentence you heard and who was the object?

Comment: @guifa I think it was llevarle, but I can't be sure. It was several days ago. The sentence would have been something like "Yo no quería llevarle su vida." which I understood to mean "I didn't want to interfere in his life."

Comment: Welcome to our site, and thanks for the good first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably subject to some regional flavor variation, and I'm not very familiar with Dominican Spanish, but here's my guess.

"Llevar" is sometimes used as *drive* or *guide*. In this context it could mean to make someone else's decisions.

I.e: I understand "Yo no quería llevarle su vida" approximately as "I didn't want to make his/her choices" or "I didn't want to be responsible for where he/she took his life to".

About *llevar* with this meaning, it's very usual. As in *"llevar a alguien de la mano"*: *take someone by the hand*.

Comment: Wow. This is really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is is that she was trying to convey what you guessed in your comment

> Yo no quería llevarle la vida <sub>I didn't want to interfere in his life; I didn't want to cause him pain</sub>.

Your hunch is probably right, since you have most of the context of that conversation.

Nevertheless, the expression

> llevarte la vida / llevarte toda la vida

usually means "to take a long time".

> Contar todas las estrellas del cielo podría llevarte toda la vida
>
> Estás pintando las paredes con ese pincel tan pequeño? Así va a llevarte toda la vida
>
> Aprender bien takewondo te puede llevar la vida
>
> Juanito está contando los granos de arroz de ese paquete. Le va a llevar la vida

Please, note that this expression id different from "llevar una vida"  <sub>To life a live (e.g to live a life of excess, llevar una vida de exceso)</sub>  or "llevársele su vida" <sub>Take his life</sub> .

Comment: También he visto otro significado como ser el enfoque principal de tu vida, o la cosa que te conduce en la vida.  Pero no sé si el uso es común ni de su extensión geográfica

Comment: @guifa, si lo he visto usado de esa manera alguna vez ahora no caigo...

Comment: A veces *llevar* significa el tiempo que tardamos: *Me llevó una vida*, *me llevó una eternidad*, *me llevó una hora*... En ese caso *llevar* es *take*.